# Unable to use <link> tag in Razor View

Tags: razor, view, hyperlink, rss, umbraco

If I use the following code the view renders fine.
But if I change the url to the necessary RSS spec.  the view will not render and throws an error saying that the  tag is invalid so the error is occurring at the link tag. No matter what I try the link tag inside the razor foreach will not compile correctly.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.RSsfeed>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@{ 
    Layout = null;
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    var rootNode = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().First();
    var newsNodes = umbraco.uQuery.GetNodesByType("newsDetail");
}<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- News Aritcles -->
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:newsArticles="https://xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx/news">
    <channel>
        <title>News Aritcles</title>
        <link>https://xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx/news</link>
        <description>News Aritcles</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <ttl>1440</ttl>
    @foreach(var newsNode in newsNodes){
        var newsContent = UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache.GetById(newsNode.Id);
        string nnDescription = newsContent.GetPropertyValue("description").ToString();
        string nnPublishDate = newsContent.GetPropertyValue("publishDate").ToString();
        <item>
            <title>@newsNode.Name</title>
            <url>https://xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx@{@newsNode.Url}</url>
            <description>@nnDescription</description>
            <pubDate>@nnPublishDate</pubDate>
            <guid>https://xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx@{@newsNode.Url}</guid>
        </item>
    }
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Any `@` characters in the URL? Can you show us actually buggy code?

Answer (score 0):

`<link/>` is a void element, and so only has a start tag and no end tag - See [W3C HTML Language Reference](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/link.html#link-tags)

You could output the tag like this

```
@("<link>" + newsNode.Url + "</link>")
```

Hope this helps